# Stored procedure not fetching data even-though the sqlsrv_query has no errors

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlsrv

I have a stored procedure with 2 parameters. I'm able to execute stored procedures with one parameter using the same script below. But I couldn't make it work with two parameters.

```
$stmt = "{CALL VM_GETPRs_CAMPS (?,?)}";**//SP has 160 rows of data.**

$fdate=date("Y-m-d");
$tdate=date("Y-m-d");

$params = array( 
                 array($fdate,SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                 array($tdate,SQLSRV_PARAM_IN)                                               
               );

$result = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $stmt,$params,array('Scrollable' => 'buffered'));   //not getting any error 

if( $result === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
} else{
    **//**I tried sqlsrv_num_rows and sqlsrv_has_rows both are giving zero rows.**
    $row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows( $result );  
    if ($row_count === false)
        echo "No rows";
    else if ($row_count >=0)
      echo "\n$row_count\n";

if(sqlsrv_has_rows($result))
    echo "has rows";
else 
    echo "No rows";
exit();
```

I'm looking for a solution since two days. Please help me.

Comment: `$stmt = "{CALL VM_GETPRs_CAMPS (?,?)}"` remove the braces `{}`

Comment: Removing braces is triggering syntax error. not working.

Comment: Did you remove `SET NOCOUNT ON` in your stored procedure?

Comment: There is no set nocount on in stored procedure. The stored procedure is having SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO. @alalp

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
"execute VM_GETPRs_CAMPS ?,?"
```

Also if you have any PRINT statement on your stored procedure may cause some trouble

Comment: This would be better as a comment, especially given that you're unsure as to whether or not it will solve OP's issue.